# Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, console-application, .net-6.0

I have developed a simple console application in .NET6 with target Platform x86 which contains 1 project only with the following packages:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client (6.0.5)

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common(6.0.5)

  Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core(1.1.0)

  System.IO.Ports (6.0.0)

Also it contains an API to communicate with a Dispenser.

This console application send and recieve data with main software throught SignalR and send and recieve data with Dispenser throught API.

I don't use any dependency injection and the Dispenser response when I try to initialize it is the next one:

```
Método no encontrado: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'.
```

Any idea why the response is that?

Comment: Looks like it is missing a library. Try to install Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider in the project from nuget.

Comment: I just installed and the error persits.

Comment: @JesusHedo Try to turn off compiler optimizations, open project properties, then go to "Build - General". There are options to enable/disable compiler optimizations under title "Optimize code".

Comment: Please share the code using signalr especially the line throwing the exception.

Comment: @JHBonarius I would guess that connecting to server would not require all of ASP.NET Core as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

[`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/) seems to be a legacy package (last updated in 2018) and was build against `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0)`, while `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` is transitively using `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (>= 6.0.0)` so the later version should be resolved during build. And it definitely has some breaking changes (like removal or signature changes of `ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection)` method)

Try removing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core` package, [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/6.0.5) should be [sufficient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0) enough to connect to the SingnalR server.

Comment: @JHBonarius the problem clearly comes from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core` which seems to be a legacy package which should not be used. Also you can create clients [without DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Aha, I learned something today. I think that link is the answer. Follow that guide (and don't install other random packages)

Comment: But my console application is a server too, also manage requests

Comment: @JesusHedo AFAIK you need web application to [host SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: @JesusHedo also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736492/2501279) answer.