# Which SignalR package to install for a .NET 6 server project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-6.0

I have a NET6 project which is built part of a larger .NET 6 ASP.NET solution. The project still references:

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR, and
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core

Which have now been marked as deprecated.

What packages do I need to install for their replacement?

The problem is that currently SignalR is located in an assembly separate from the main ASP.NET project. This is because the main project and a couple of other projects within the solution use the hubs (using constructor DI).

If I change the SignalR project to

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    ...
</Project>
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Error CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

So the problem is that I cannot have a common assembly with SignalR referenced by multiple other projects.

Comment: You could check out this - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/. Here it says that Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core is deprecated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SignalR` is included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-6.0)). Change the console app SDK to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
   ...
</Project>
```

To use the ASP.NET Core shared framework in a [class library project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) - add `FrameworkReference` element for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This works only if the project is the main one. I have SignalR in a separate project in which I define my hubs and is reference in the main ASP.NET project and other projects within the solution.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono "This works only if the project is the main one" - can you please elaborate? You can't change the separate project to target web sdk?

Comment: Doing so requires that the project has a static 'Main' method.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono see the update.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Can also just change the output type in the project file:
`<OutputType>Library</OutputType>`. The reason it requires a Main method is because by default it will be `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`

Comment: @MohammadTaherian which one?

Comment: @MohammadTaherian please read the answer, it does not say to add package. And the [frameworkreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  it says to add is far from being deprecated.